# Difference between extending a class conforming to a protocol VS extending a protocol based on similar condition?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I was going through [this link.](http://krakendev.io/blog/subclassing-can-suck-and-heres-why)

But I dont really get the logical difference between the below two code snippets:

**1. Extending ONLY those UIViewControllers which conform to protocol ErrorPopoverRenderer .**

```
protocol ErrorPopoverRenderer {
    func presentError(message: String, withArrow shouldShowArrow: Bool, backgroundColor: UIColor, withSize size: CGSize, canDismissByTappingAnywhere canDismiss: Bool)
} 

extension UIViewController: ErrorPopoverRenderer { //Make all the UIViewControllers that conform to ErrorPopoverRenderer have a default implementation of presentError
    func presentError(message: String, withArrow shouldShowArrow: Bool, backgroundColor: UIColor, withSize size: CGSize, canDismissByTappingAnywhere canDismiss: Bool) 
{}
}
```

**2.  Extending the protocol for ONLY those UIViewControllers which conform to it.**

```
extension ErrorPopoverRenderer where Self: UIViewController {
func presentError() {
}
}
```

***Either ways, Any UIViewController subclass which will conform to the protocol will have default method implementation but in UIviewcontroller extension OR protocol extension.
What is the logical diffference? 
Please correct me if I am wrong***

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that the first:

```
extension UIViewController: ErrorPopoverRenderer { }
```

actually **extends** `UIViewController` class, so every instance of `UIViewController` has now access to methods & properties from the protocol. **It doesn't mean that it will extend the class that implements the protocol, it means that right now you are implementing the protocol for this class**. Usually you have to implement some of the methods & properties in that extension.

Where in second one:

```
extension ErrorPopoverRenderer where Self: UIViewController {}
```

you actually add methods & properties for `UIViewController` that implements the protocol `ErrorPopoverRenderer`.

Basically in first you extend the class with whole protocol implementation, and in the second one you extend class, but **only** if this class or subclass implements the protocol `ErrorPopoverRenderer`.

Answer (score 1):

**1**

First of all, you create a protocol `ErrorPopoverRenderer` with a *blueprint* for method `presentError(...)`. You thereafter extend the class `UIViewController` to conform to this protocol, by implementing the (compulsory) blueprint for method `presentError(...)`.

This means that you can subclass `UIViewController)` with additional protocol constraint `ErrorPopoverRenderer` for the subclass. If `UIViewController` had not been extended to conform to protocol  `ErrorPopoverRenderer`, the subsequent code in the example you linked would case compile time error (`... does not comply to protocol ErrorPopoverRenderer`)

```
class KrakenViewController: UIViewController, ErrorPopoverRenderer {
    func failedToEatHuman() {
        //…
        //Throw error because the Kraken sucks at eating Humans today.
        presentError(ErrorOptions(message: "Oh noes! I didn't get to eat the Human!", size: CGSize(width: 1000.0, height: 200.0))) //Woohoo! We can provide whatever parameters we want, or no parameters at all!
    }
}
```

However, there is a possible issue with this method, as presented in your link:

> Now we have to implement every parameter every time we want to present
>   an ErrorView. This kind of sucks because we can’t provide default
>   values to protocol function declarations.

So of the protocol `ErrorPopoverRenderer` is not intended solely for use by `UIViewController`:s (or subclasses thereof), then the solution above isn't very generic.

**2**

If we want to have a more broad use of `ErrorPopoverRenderer`, we place the *specific*  blueprints for each class type that might make use of the protocol in *protocol extensions*. This is really neat as the more specifics parts of `ErrorPopoverRenderer` blueprints for method `presentError()` can be specified differently for different classes that are to possibly conform to the protocol, and the method `presentError()` can be made more minimalistic.

I quote, from the example:

> Using **Self** here indicates that that extension will only ever take
>   place if and only if the conformer inherits from UIViewController.
>   This gives us the ability **to assume that the ErrorPopoverRenderer is
>   indeed a UIViewController** without even extending UIViewController.

In this method, since **the code now knows** (we did, already in 1.) that it is a view controller that will call `presentError()`, we can place the specific `UIViewController` stuff directly in the blueprint implementation, and needn't send it as a long list of arguments.

Hence, 2. is, for this specific use, a kind of more "generic" approach, in the sense that we slightly minimise code duplication (calling `presentError()` vs `presentError(... lots of args ...)` from several different `UIViewController`:s).